# Integrating ranger with schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, authorization, confluent-schema-registry, apache-ranger, apache-kafka-security

I'm trying to integrate **confluent schema registry** with **apache ranger** but there's no material to explain how, i copied the plugin jar into libs then i don't know where to pass the file install.properties and enable it like kafka plugin, should we pass something to inform schema registry of ranger policy admin url ?